# Weird permanent square shows up on the desktop wallpaper in Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution

For some reason, when I change my resolution to something which it normally is (1080). A weird grey box/square appears in my wallpaper and doesn’t go away until I reboot.

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

[larger view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxjHV.png)

Comment: This question lacks detail. Looks like Widows 8, correct? What have you attempted to resolve this? Have you done any research? What happens if you click the desktop and press F5? Details about your graphic card would probably help.

Comment: Yeah youre right. Its windows 8.1x64 - F5ing does nothing but refresh the icons on my desktop. Graphics card is an 770GTX 4GB.. I doubt that the issue tho. Thanks

Comment: Can you select the square? Is this an HP by chance?  Suggestions; run virus and malware scans, change themes and remove any personalization/tweak apps.

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled everything theme related and it's still there.. getting kinda desperate at this point, its bugging me.

Comment: Do a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) and see if the box still exists. If it is gone, slowly start re-enabling the items disabled previously. As soon as the box comes back, the last thing enabled is what is causing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I did a clean boot and found the program causing it.

Comment: Great. I'll post it as an answer. What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) and see if the box still exists. If it is gone, slowly start re-enabling the items disabled previously. As soon as the box comes back, the last thing enabled is what is causing it.